# Which JQuery event should be used to call a function ONCE at startup?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

I have a slider that sets motor speed `oninput` and it works well.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    
    var sliderAZ = document.getElementById("AZRange");
    var sliderEL = document.getElementById("ELRange");
    var outputAZ = document.getElementById("demoAZ");
    var outputEL = document.getElementById("demoEL");
    outputAZ.innerHTML = sliderAZ.value;
    outputEL.innerHTML = sliderEL.value;

    sliderAZ.oninput = function() {
        outputAZ.innerHTML = this.value;
        AzimuthSpeed();
    }
    
    sliderEL.oninput = function() {
        outputEL.innerHTML = this.value;
        ElevationSpeed();
    }
    
</script>
```

The problem is that I have to click on the slider (in the GUI) to get the initial input for speed. I would like to have the speed value loaded (and subsequently sent to the motor driver using JSON) like it is for the oninput event.

I have tried .ready for the document.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
        AzimuthSpeed();              
        ElevationSpeed();
```

This makes the program hang and the speed value is not shown on the web page. I'm guessing it's not even sending the default value for the speed?

I also tried using the "one" event to send the initial value once when the document is ready:

```
$(document).one( "ready", function() {
        AzimuthSpeed();              
        ElevationSpeed();
```

That didn't work either. Here is the slider HTML code:

```
<td>
    <div class="slidecontainer">
        <input type="range" min="2" max="150" value="30" class="slider" id="AZRange">
        <p>Speed: <span id="demoAZ"></span></p>
    </div>
</td>
```

The speed is sent to the driver using sockets:

```
// Send speed indicated on range slider for Azimuth motor
    function AzimuthSpeed()     { socket_mc.send("AZspeed" + sliderAZ.value); }
// Send speed indicated on range slider for Elevation motor
    function ElevationSpeed()   { socket_mc.send("ELspeed" + sliderEL.value); }
```

Speed is set using the slider per the top piece of code.

What event would you recommend to set the speed to the initial value of 30?

Comment: why not use `localStorage.setItem('status')` to save `status` when we run it the first time and then check `localStorage.getItem('status')` to decide whether we need to call it or not.

Comment: How does calling `AzimuthSpeed()` within `.ready()` make the program hang?

Comment: @guest271314 It looks like the initial value of 30 is not assigned to sliderAZ.value? Having no value passed to the motor driver prevents it from running. In the original version, the value of 30 was sent to the GUI, but the slider still had to be moved to send the motor speed. I think "ready may be sending no value continually which is causing issues.

Comment: `.ready()` is called once, except for when there are multiple called to `.ready()` throughout the code. What code sets and gets the value for the motor driver?

Comment: `ready` only fires once. It bothers me that I can't see all of your code. There's no closing brackets on any of your examples, so there's more going on there than meets the eye. Also, just because the document is ready, doesn't mean the slider is ready. What library are you using for the slider? Is there no `initialize` method for it? That's where I'd start looking.

Comment: @THEtheChad Added entire script for slider. Slider is JQuery. I did not see any mention of initialization when I was researching this. The slider works in all ways except I can't send the initial value to the driver:
`// Send speed indicated on range slider for Azimuth motor
        function AzimuthSpeed()     { socket_mc.send("AZspeed" + sliderAZ.value); }
        // Send speed indicated on range slider for Elevation motor
        function ElevationSpeed()   { socket_mc.send("ELspeed" + sliderEL.value); }`

Comment: @guest271314 I will edit OP to include set and get.

Comment: `<p>Speed: <span id="demoAZ">30</span></p>` and just call the function on using your `$(document).ready()` attempt? Your `change` events are using the `innerHTML` right? Then set it in your initial markup!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `oninput` handlers are working. You call `ElevationSpeed();` after having updated the `innerHTML` of a `span`, for the user to actually see the value which comes for that markup... Which is later updated by your slider.

```
<input type="range" min="2" max="150" value="30" class="slider" id="AZRange">
```

Now you just want to have an "initial" setted on load?
See comment below, in code.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

    var sliderAZ = document.getElementById("AZRange");
    var sliderEL = document.getElementById("ELRange");
    var outputAZ = document.getElementById("demoAZ");
    var outputEL = document.getElementById("demoEL");
    outputAZ.innerHTML = sliderAZ.value;
    outputEL.innerHTML = sliderEL.value;

    sliderAZ.oninput = function() {
        outputAZ.innerHTML = this.value;
        AzimuthSpeed();
    }

    sliderEL.oninput = function() {
        outputEL.innerHTML = this.value;
        ElevationSpeed();
    }

    // Why not just call the function on load here?
    AzimuthSpeed();

</script>
```

Now, the function has to exist before that call... That's all.